# Call a non-default constructor in from a generic list instantiation

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I have a class called Fred whose constructor takes a parameter parmA that I want to pass into the initialisation of a generic List of type MultiCtorClass called MyList.

The default constructor for MultiCtorClass passes ParmB to its base; I want to call the other constructor of MultiCtorClass passing in parmA from the initialisation of Fred.

```
public class Fred
{
    public Fred(parmType parmA)
    {
        MyList = new List<MultiCtorClass>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<MultiCtorClass> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class MultiCtorClass : MyBase
{
    public MultiCtorClass()
        : this(parmB)
    {
    }

    public MultiCtorClass(parmType parm)
        : base(parm)
    {
    }
}
```

I am actually trying to do the following:

```
    public Fred(parmType parmA)
    {
        MyList = new List<MultiCtorClass(parmA)>();
    }
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Look into `Reflection` to instantiate the list items. You can't constrain the list itself to only items who were instantiated with a specific ctor, however.

Comment: Is there a reason MultiCtorParm class can't take a generic too?

Comment: @Tim Barrass Only the fact that this is all legacy code used throughout our system and making that kind of change will have a huge ripple effect. I'm looking / hoping for a simple quick solution / work around before going down the refactor route

Answer (score 4):

You're not calling any constructor in either case - the list is empty. You only call the constructor when creating a new item, e.g.

```
MyList.Add(new MultiCtorClass(...));
```

And you can pick your constructor at will there :)

Comment: And if you want to be fancy: MyList = new List<MultiCtorClass> { new MultiCtorClass(paramA) };